# Remove underscore from php echo output

Tags: php

How do i remove underscore from this echo?

```
if($validation->fails())
{
    echo '<div class="error_message">', ($validation->errors()->first('first_name')), '</div>';
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what madness is this?

```
if($validation->fails()) {
  echo '<div class="error_message">' . str_replace("_"," ",($validation->errors()->first('first_name'))) . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace a string char you have to use `str_replace` function.
Here is an example:

```
$var = "Hello_World";
$var = str_replace("_"," ",$var);
echo $var;
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```